# Error in Test Class :Quote has no pricebook assigned

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me out with this Error :

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The pricebook entry is in a
>   different pricebook than the one assigned to the Quote, or Quote has
>   no pricebook assigned.: [PricebookEntryId]

The Error line is :

```
insert qli;
```

Test Class :

```
@istest
public class TestQuoteContentController{
static TestMethod void QuoteContenttest(){

Date closeDt = Date.Today();

date myDate = date.today();

// load the page

 PageReference pageRef = Page.RFQInformation;
   Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

  // QuoteContentController qc = new QuoteContentController();
  //apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('Id','q.Id');

  // set up Account and Verify that the results are as expected.

Account ac = new Account(Name = 'RFQ test acc',BillingStreet='A',
                         BillingCity='Hyderabad',BillingState='TS',
                         BillingCountry='INDIA',BillingPostalCode='500075',Main_Customers_of_Account__c='Home Depot' ,
                         Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c='Cree',Servicing_Region__c='AP',Annual_LED_Revenue__c=500,
                         Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c=1000,
                         Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c=10);
  insert ac;

  // set up opportunity and Verify that the results are as expected.

opportunity oppy = new opportunity(Name='testing RFQ ' ,  AccountId= ac.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt, Shipment_Info__c='test',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line1__c='Road No 37',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line2__c='Jubilee Hills',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line3__c='Land Mark Neerus',
                                   Shipping_City__c='Hyd',
                                   Shipping_State_Province__c='TS',
                                   Shipping_Zipcode__c='500081',
                                   Shipping_Country__c ='India',
                                   Bill_of_Lading__c='This is waybill1 this is waybill 2 waybill3 -34958309458 waybill - 44570375',
                                   Probability=20 ,AccSegment__c='Commercial Entertainment',
                                   AccApplication__c='Indoor  Lamps  Decorative', Persona__c='Institution',Region__c='AP');
insert oppy;

// set up product and Verify that the results are as expected.

  Product2 pro = new Product2(Product_Line__c='Test RFQ Form',Name='BXCD12',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXCD2434', isActive=true);
  insert pro;

 // set up pricebook and Verify that the results are as expected.

 Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2(Name='RFQ test');
 insert pb2;

// set up pricebookentry and Verify that the results are as expected.

PricebookEntry pbe =new PricebookEntry(unitprice=0.01,Product2Id=pro.Id,Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId(),isActive=true,UseStandardPrice = false
);
 insert pbe;

// set up opportunitylineitem and Verify that the results are as expected.

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem = new OpportunityLineItem 
                                   (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=oppy.Id,UnitPrice=0.01,PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id);
 insert OPplineitem;

 // set up Quote and Verify that the results are as expected.
 Quote q = new Quote(Name='test-RFQ' ,//QuoteNumber='0000709',
                    Effective_Date__c=myDate ,
                    Comments__c='Testing RFQ Information', OpportunityId=oppy.Id
                    );
insert q;

 // set up Quotelineitem and Verify that the results are as expected.
 QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem(//Name='BXRC-37F1001-B-03' ,
                                      Unitprice=0.01 ,
                                      End_Customer_Price__c=5000 ,
                                      Quantity=2 , 
                                      //TotalPrice=0.01,
                                      QuoteId=q.Id,PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id, Product2Id=pro.Id);
insert qli;

 // set up Competitors and Verify that the results are as expected. 
 Competitor__c com = new Competitor__c(Part_Number__c='Nichia',
                             Product_Series__c='VS',
                             Price_Offered__c=5000,
                             Volume__c=1000,
                             Date_Price_is_Valid__c=myDate);
 insert com;


  // set up gmodOpportunityForecast and Verify that the results are as expected.

  gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opf =new gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c(gmod__Quantity__c=1000, 
                                                    gmod__Quarter__c=2 ,
                                                   // gmod__Amount__c =10000,
                                                    gmod__Year__c=2015 );
                                                   // gmod__Month_Text__c='april' );
                                                   // gmod__Product__r.Name='BXRC-25E4000-F-04' );

insert opf;

QuoteContentController.wrapperClass w = new QuoteContentController.wrapperClass ();

list<QuoteContentController.wrapperClass>  disp_list =new list<QuoteContentController.wrapperClass>(); 
    disp_list.add(w);

}
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please ask a concrete question, do not paste whole your code.

Comment: The obvious thing to try to do to resolve the `Quote has no pricebook assigned` error would be to assign a pricebook to the quote

Answer (score 1):

Just as @BarCotter suggested, you need to assign the `Quote` record with a Pricebook Id. You simply do the following in your test class:

```
Quote testQuote = new Quote(Name = 'test-RFQ', Effective_Date__c = myDate, 
    Comments__c = 'Testing RFQ Information', OpportunityId = oppy.Id, 
    /*Here's the clincher. You should add this... (Chevelle reference)*/ 
    Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId());

INSERT testQuote;
```

> ***Please note:*** Whenever you link up a `Quote` with a `QuoteLineItem` make sure that your `Quote` and `QuoteLineItem` share the same `Pricebook2Id`. Otherwise, you'll run into an issue there as well.